# Evaluating the limit $\lim_{h\to 0} \frac{\sqrt {1 - (x+h) ^2} - \sqrt {1-x^2}} {h}$

Tags: calculus, limits

Find the limit

$\lim_{h\to 0} \frac{\sqrt {1 - (x+h) ^2} - \sqrt {1-x^2}} {h}$

I tried substituting "h" and also multiplying $\frac{\sqrt {1 - (x+h) ^2} + \sqrt {1-x^2}}{\sqrt {1 - (x+h) ^2} + \sqrt {1-x^2}}$

Comment: this is a derivative

Comment: That seems to work (the "multiplying" thing). Where di you get stack?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your idea is fine, indeed we obtain

$$\frac{\sqrt {1 - (x+h) ^2} - \sqrt {1-x^2}} {h}\cdot \frac{\sqrt {1 - (x+h) ^2} + \sqrt {1-x^2}}{\sqrt {1 - (x+h) ^2} + \sqrt {1-x^2}}=$$

$$=\frac{{1 - (x+h) ^2} -  ({1-x^2})}{h(\sqrt {1 - (x+h) ^2} + \sqrt {1-x^2})}=$$

$$=\frac{-2xh-h^2}{h(\sqrt {1 - (x+h) ^2} + \sqrt {1-x^2})}$$

and since $h$ cancels out we can conclude.

Comment: how do you get $=\frac{-2xh}{h(\sqrt {1 - (x+h) ^2} + \sqrt {1-x^2})}$ ? I'm getting $=\frac{-2xh - h^2 + 2x - 2x^2 }{h(\sqrt {1 - (x+h) ^2} + \sqrt {1-x^2})}$

Comment: @ya23 I forgot a $h^2$, I fix that. We have $$1 - (x+h) ^2 -  (1-x^2)=1-x^2-2hx-h^2-1+x^2=-2hx-h^2$$

Answer (score 1):

Let $f(x)=\sqrt{1-x^2}$

$$f'(x)=\lim_{h \to 0}\frac{\sqrt{1-({x+h})^2}-\sqrt{1-x^2}}{h}=\frac{-x}{\sqrt{1-x^2}}$$